# Is ftp.storbinary not the same as ftp.retrbinary?

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to download and upload to an FTP server. The download works just fine, but the upload is spitting out this error:

Error: AttributeError("'function' object has no attribute 'read'",)

```
def download_handle(block):
    global sizeWritten
    dFile.write(block)
    os.system('CLS')
    sizeWritten += len(block)
    percentComplete = sizeWritten / totalSize
    percentComplete = round((percentComplete*100),1)

    print (percentComplete, "% complete")

try:
    dFile = open('filename', "wb")
    print("DL File opened")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, download_handle)
    print("Download Completed")
    dFile.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", repr(e))

def upload_handle(block):
    global sizeWritten
    upFile.write(block)
    os.system('CLS')
    percentComplete = sizeWritten / totalSize
    percentComplete = round((percentComplete*100),1)

    print (percentComplete, "% complete")


try:
    upFile = open('filename', "rb")
    print("UL File opened")
    ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, upload_handle)
    print ("Upload completed")
    upFile.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", repr(e))
```

Comment: You never assign `download_handle`, or, for that matter, `upload_handle`. Please post *working* code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `retrbinary` method requires you to pass a function that will be used to write the data. Usually you should be passing `dFile.write`. I don't know what `download_handle` is because you don't define it, but it's probably not the correct method. Similarly, for `storbinary` you want to pass in `upFile.read`.

Comment: Added function calls, sorry for delay